# retrieving selected features from RFECV inside gridsearchCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-selection, grid-search, rfe

I want to write a code that grid searches over  a couple of processors and preprocessors, but also over different combinations of features. I did this by using RFECV inside a gridsearchCV. However, this takes ages to run. Therefor, I reversed the order. I did a grid search and then I put it inside RFECV. Now, I want to see and print which features are actually selected in the best model. I tried a couple of solutions from this website, but none of them have worked. How can I access the selected features? Both `grid_dem.get_support(indices=True)` and `grid_dem.support_` did not work. I get this and other similar errors: `AttributeError: 'RFECV' object has no attribute 'support_'`

The relevant part of my code is:

```
pipe = Pipeline([('preprocessing', StandardScaler()), ('rbf_svm', SVC(max_iter=1e6))])
param_grid ={'preprocessing': [StandardScaler(), MinMaxScaler(), Normalizer(), RobustScaler()],
     'rbf_svm__kernel': ['rbf', 'poly', 'linear', 'sigmoid'],
     'rbf_svm__C': np.logspace(-3,2,5), 'rbf_svm__gamma': np.logspace(-3,2,5)}

    # {'preprocessing': [StandardScaler(), MinMaxScaler(), Normalizer(), RobustScaler()],
    #  'rbf_svm': [LogisticRegression(max_iter=1e6)],
    #  'logisticregression__C': np.logspace(-3,2,5)}]

grid_dem = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid, cv=5,verbose=5,n_jobs=3)
grid_dem.fit(X_democrat_train,y_democrat_train)
grid_dem.score(X_democrat_test,y_democrat_test)
print(grid_dem.best_estimator_)
rfecv=RFECV(grid_dem, verbose=3)
print(rfecv)
print(rfecv.get_support(indices=True))
# rfecv=rfecv.fit_transform(X_democrat_train, y_democrat_train)
# print(rfecv.get_params())
```

As you can see in the last two lines, I also tried to transform the X, but this did not work either.

Answer (score 1):

You have sent a pipeline to gridSearch. So the `best_estimator_` will return a pipeline. But`grid_dem` is still a GridSearchCV object. So obviously `get_support()` will not work. After that you passed this `grid_dem` to `RFECV` but did not call `fit()` on it. Thats why the `support_` is not available.

Please update your code like this:

```
rfecv=RFECV(grid_dem.best_estimator_, verbose=3)  <==Edited
rfecv.fit(X_democrat_train,y_democrat_train)   #<==This is what you want
print(rfecv.get_support(indices=True))  
# rfecv=rfecv.fit_transform(X_democrat_train, y_democrat_train)
# print(rfecv.get_params())mocrat_train,y_democrat_train)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried your update, but I get the following error: 'RuntimeError: The classifier does not expose "coef_" or "feature_importances_" attributes'. What should I do with this?

Comment: @Kate Yes. Thats because GridSearchCV dont have those and RFECV can be only used with those estimators which have one of these attributes. Try the edited answer.

Comment: @VivekKumar Please let me know if you know an answer for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55650782/how-to-get-the-selected-features-in-gridsearchcv-in-sklearn-in-python Looking forward to hearing from you. Thank you very much :)