# How to get the selected features in GridSearchCV in sklearn in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-mining, gridsearchcv

I am using `recurive feature elimination with cross validation (rfecv)` as the feature selection technique with `GridSearchCV`.

My code is as follows.

```
X = df[my_features_all]
y = df['gold_standard']

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)

k_fold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=0)

clf = RandomForestClassifier(random_state = 42, class_weight="balanced")

rfecv = RFECV(estimator=clf, step=1, cv=k_fold, scoring='roc_auc')

param_grid = {'estimator__n_estimators': [200, 500],
    'estimator__max_features': ['auto', 'sqrt', 'log2'],
    'estimator__max_depth' : [3,4,5]
    }

CV_rfc = GridSearchCV(estimator=rfecv, param_grid=param_grid, cv= k_fold, scoring = 'roc_auc', verbose=10, n_jobs = 5)
CV_rfc.fit(x_train, y_train)
print("Finished feature selection and parameter tuning")
```

Now, I want to get the `optimal number of features` and `selected features` from the above code.

For that I ran the below code.

```
#feature selection results
print("Optimal number of features : %d" % rfecv.n_features_)
features=list(X.columns[rfecv.support_])
print(features)
```

However, I got the following error:
`AttributeError: 'RFECV' object has no attribute 'n_features_'`.

Is there any other way of getting these details?

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object `rfecv` that you passed to `GridSearchCV` is not fitted by it. It is first cloned and those clones are then fitted to data and evaluated for all the different combinations of hyperparameters.

So to access the best features, you would need to access the `best_estimator_` attribute of the `GridSearchCV`:-

```
CV_rfc.fit(x_train, y_train)
print("Finished feature selection and parameter tuning")

print("Optimal number of features : %d" % rfecv.n_features_)
features=list(X.columns[CV_rfc.best_estimator_.support_])
print(features)
```

Comment: thanks a lot. that worked :) just a quick question. is the process I have used above is correct? i.e. first I perform `rfecv` and then `gridsearchcv`. Looking forward to hearing from you. thank you very much :)

Comment: Please let me know if you know an answer for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55671530/why-do-i-get-different-values-with-pipline-and-without-pipline-in-sklearn-in-pyt Thank you very much :)